# display list of posts/pages in admin edit post/page

Tags: posts, wp-admin

Basically, I thinking how i could get a mini wp-admin/edit.php view inside the wp-admin/post.php page. does this even make sense to anyone?

Comment: Steve, I suggest adding more information to clarify your question. It might even be helpful to include a screenshot to show what you're trying to accomplish, and anything you might have already tried to accomplish it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I expected this. Ok maybe if i slow down it will help. So if you click on pages in the admin section you'll get a list of all your pages right? right. you'll also have access to the quick-edit functions. Now imagine if that exactly list with all its functionality was viewable while editing a pages content. hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [CMS Tree Page View](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-tree-page-view/) plugin (my favorite) or the [Easily navigate pages on dashboard](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easily-navigate-pages-on-your-dashboard/) plugin. Both allow you to have a list of your pages on the Dashboard.

[image: Easily navigate pages screenshot]

Then you should be able to add that panel using this reference:
add_meta_box to integrate the box that appears on the Dashboard (see wp_add_dashboard_widget in functions.php of CMS Tree Page View)

Comment: ok awesome. now I guess i just need to find the hooks that call...umm the template box and add the tree view page function to the hook? right?

Comment: Yes - see my edits.

Comment: wow this is great. I really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [Admin Menu Tree Page View](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-tree-page-view/). It's like the above mentioned CMS Tree Page View, but always visible in the left admin menu. I think it sounds more like what you're looking for.

The plugin looks like this:
[screenshots](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-tree-page-view/screenshots/).